# How can I "track" which tables matched my multi-table, multi-word search query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm building a relatively simple search engine in which I want to to figure out where my hits came from. So, for instance, if I have table A, B and C, and I search for `lorem ipsum`, I was hoping to have an output like:

```
// Example output in php. Only 'lorem' was found, in A

$output = [
  'results' => [...]
  'matches' => [
    'A' => ['lorem'],
    'B' => [],
    'C' => []
];
```

I already have the multi-word, multi-table working nicely, but I have no idea how to track where the data came from. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the query you run for the search. Might need to use a `union`.

Comment: Or even more likely, you need to do this in php after you get the results back from mysql. Sql language does not care which table generated the hit, so there is no intrinsic feature you can rely on.

Comment: @Shadow the project is still at its early stages so we could switch to PG. Would it help?

Comment: If by PG you mean postgresql, then no, it would not really help, since it also uses sql. In general, SQL does not care where there results come from. In complex query it is often impossible to say, since the filtering conditions may be applied against multiple tables. Not to mention subqueries, derived tables, views, etc.